# Ionic2 IOS failed while android OK

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2

I'm building an application with Ionic2 cordova.

I don't understand why the application is running fine on Chrome (ionic serve) and android (ionic run android) while it's not on safari (ionic serve) and xcode emulator (ionic run ios).

The application launches the splashscreen on xcode emulator then stays blank.

Here is my ionic info:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.37
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.2.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3 Build version 7D175
```

I opened the project on xcode, and here is the errors I get:

```
2016-08-21 17:59:30.175 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/GM/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3DEADFD6-D4D5-437C-9DBA-2FC8D02DA537/data/Containers/Data/Application/C7FE4875-2781-4FC8-9B68-AA6E1F8BCA7D/Library/Cookies/com.yin.woocommerce.binarycookies
2016-08-21 17:59:30.221 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.1.1 is starting.
2016-08-21 17:59:30.222 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2016-08-21 17:59:30.273 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] CDVWKWebViewEngine: trying to inject XHR polyfill
2016-08-21 17:59:30.277 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume
2016-08-21 17:59:30.277 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] Using WKWebView
2016-08-21 17:59:30.278 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.079989ms
2016-08-21 17:59:30.280 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.766980ms
2016-08-21 17:59:30.280 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.063002ms
2016-08-21 17:59:30.280 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] CDVPlugin class CDVSplashScreen (pluginName: splashscreen) does not exist.
2016-08-21 17:59:30.280 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 0.165999ms
2016-08-21 17:59:30.280 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] CDVPlugin class IonicKeyboard (pluginName: keyboard) does not exist.
2016-08-21 17:59:30.280 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 0.117004ms
2016-08-21 17:59:30.281 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] CDVPlugin class CDVStatusBar (pluginName: statusbar) does not exist.
2016-08-21 17:59:30.296 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 15.504956ms
2016-08-21 17:59:30.296 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 18.702984ms
2016-08-21 17:59:30.719 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] CDVPlugin class CDVDevice (pluginName: Device) does not exist.
2016-08-21 17:59:30.720 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] ERROR: Plugin 'Device' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2016-08-21 17:59:30.720 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] FAILED pluginJSON = ["Device1663822631","Device","getDeviceInfo",[]]
2016-08-21 17:59:30.721 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] CDVPlugin class CDVStatusBar (pluginName: StatusBar) does not exist.
2016-08-21 17:59:30.721 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] ERROR: Plugin 'StatusBar' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2016-08-21 17:59:30.721 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564273] FAILED pluginJSON = ["StatusBar1663822632","StatusBar","_ready",[]]
2016-08-21 17:59:30.958 Woocommerce Mobile[70183:8564598] CDVWKWebViewEngine: XHR intercepted: build/app.html
```

And finally my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>Woocommerce Mobile</name>
  <description>Woocommerce Mobile Application</description>
  <author email="" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Mobile Division</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57"/>
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114"/>
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40"/>
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80"/>
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120"/>
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50"/>
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100"/>
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60"/>
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120"/>
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180"/>
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72"/>
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144"/>
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76"/>
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152"/>
    <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167"/>
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29"/>
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58"/>
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87"/>
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640"/>
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750"/>
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242"/>
    <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208"/>
    <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048"/>
    <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024"/>
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536"/>
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768"/>
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640"/>
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320"/>
  </platform>
  <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine"/>
  </feature>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
  </feature>
  <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000"/>
  <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.2"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.3"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.2"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.2.2"/>
  <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.1.3"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git"/>
</widget>
```

Any idea why this is working fine on android and not on ios? Sorry for my noobness, this is all new for me...

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried by installing `ios-deploy` too?

Comment: Yes thanks just tried and not working too...Really don't understand why it's working on android.